# Putting main WordPress blog under a different folder name

Tags: cms, configuration, customization

I want to use WordPress primarily as a static page CMS for a small business site.

I want to use the "pages" feature for most of the pages on the site, except for a news blog, for which I want to use the blogging part of WordPress.

So I want a structure like this:

example.com - main page

example.com/about

example.com/location

example.com/services

example.com/news

Where the first four are "pages" that don't need dynamic content, but the "news" part is a blog with company news, etc.

How do I implement a URL structure like this? If I install Wordpress to example.com/news folder, all the pages look like this: example.com/news/about

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on [duncmc's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8971/putting-main-wordpress-blog-under-a-different-folder-name/8972#8972),

> Install WordPress in the root directory of your site. Then log in to the WP Admin, go to Settings > Reading and specify a static page for the front page of your site.

and [Tnorthcutt's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8971/putting-main-wordpress-blog-under-a-different-folder-name/8973#8973),

> you also need to specify which page you want blog posts to show up on. That's done on the same Settings -> Reading page:
>   [image]

(which summed up the answer of your question), follow these steps. I assume that you've already installed WordPress, so I'll skip this part.

1. Fist, login to your WordPress dashboard, go to *Settings -> Permalinks* and set your **permalinks** structure to something different from the default one. Example: `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`
2. Go to *Page -> Add New* and create a the page you want to represent your homepage. Example: Home. Save your new page.
3. Create another page, this time called *News* (or anything you would like to call your news page). Save it.
4. Go *Settings -> Reading* (you will see the screenshot submitted by Tnorthcutt), now, choose 'A static page' option and set your home and news page from the drop down select boxes.
5. Now, you can go to Appearance -> Menus and set your navigation menu for your site.

The above guys answered it, but I wanted to extend their answers step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Install WordPress in the root directory of your site. Then log in to the WP Admin, go to Settings > Reading and specify a static page for the front page of your site.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on duncmc's answer, you also need to specify which page you want blog posts to show up on. That's done on the same Settings -> Reading page:
[image]